# Does jQuery $.when handles several ajax requests at differents times?

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
function myFunc() {
    console.log('called!');
} 

var url = $.get('/api/example.json');

$.when(url).then(function(response) {
    myFunc();
});
```

How can I make `myFunc` get called **everytime** `url` gets requested?

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    // how can I call url and fire myFunc()?
    url();
}
```

I need it to log:

```
// called!
// called!
// called!
// called!
// called!
// called!
// called!
// called!
// called!
```

Do I need to initialize a $.Deferred object?
How can I do that?

Comment: What exactly are you wanting to acheive? You can use `myfunc` as callback of `$.get` to get the logging shown. Explain what you expect from `$.when`. You can also pass array or promises to `$.when` to fire specific code after all ajax calls are done

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could just do it like this:

```
function myFunc() {
    console.log('called!');
} 

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    $.get('/api/example.json').done(myFunc); // get your file, and when it's done, call myFunc.
}
```

Hope this helps!